# MySQL or Laravel Eloquent - order by

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I need to order records by year (from newest to oldest), where column's content looks like:

```
id | year
-------------
1  | 1Q 2000
2  | 4Q 2000
3  | 3Q 1999
4  | 1Q 2002
```

1Q, 2Q, 3Q, 4Q means quarter. I need to get result:

```
id | year
-------------
4  | 1Q 2002
2  | 4Q 2000 (4th quarter of 2000 is newest than 1 quarter of 2000)
1  | 1Q 2000
3  | 3Q 1999
```

1. Is it possible in MySQL ?
2. Is it possible in Laravel Eloquent ->orderBy() ?

Thank you,
Kind regards,
Paul

Comment: Presumably you've considered breaking the year and the quarter up into two separate columns, so you can just do this the easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `MySQL` you can use `RIGHT` to get year part first, then you need to order by `year` column once more to get correct ordering for multiple quarters with the same year:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_tab
ORDER BY RIGHT(year, 4) DESC, year DESC   -- LEFT(year, 1) DESC
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/069b3/1/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

use `CAST` or `RIGHT`

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(year, 4) AS UNSIGNED) DESC,year DESC
```

Comment: Your code  `ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(year, 4) AS UNSIGNED) DESC` won't work with multiple quarters the same year. Check [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c3b9f/2/0)

Comment: SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(year, 4) AS UNSIGNED) DESC, year DESC